# Django doesn't load static files from S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I finally made it to run 'python manage.py collectstatic' to upload staticfiles to my S3 bucket.

But after running 'sudo service apache2 restart', my page doesn't load staticfiles although my S3 Bucket has 'static' directory including all static files.

How can I solve this problem?

I include static files like below :

```
{% load compress %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href ="{% static 'bower_components/.../bootstrap.css' % /}
...
{% endcompress %}
```

My `settings.py` is below:

```
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + '/static/' # which is the path of the static directory included in my S3 Bucket

STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_URL

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

Is there anything I'm missing now?

Comment: Are you able to view your static content in a browser without going via django? My quick guess is that your bucket isn't setup for public access.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton Yes, I can see my static content with the url : https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/MY_BUCKET_NAME/static/MY_CSS_DIRECTORY/MY_CSS.css

Comment: Do you mean the code in browser? It doesn't show any static file codes so we can notice that it doesn't load static files.

Comment: You answered my question the first time. If you can load css/javascript by visiting the url directly then it's unlikely a permissions problem on your bucket. Have you used web inspector and network tab to see what django is outputting as a link and what the actual error is?

Comment: Guys, Do I need to change httpd.conf file related to static files to correct this issue?

Comment: Probably not - since you should be outputting links directly to S3. That's why I asked what django was generating and if you'd inspected the network tab.

Comment: [Using Amazon S3 to Store your Django Site's Static and Media Files](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/)